# Microsoft Office Word in a web browser

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I want to have a Microsoft office word inside a web browser so that i can get the control to format the text and specify proper indentation. I don't want a client side to save the document.
It should be the same as http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/htmleditor/htmleditor.aspx but i want an additonal component i.e RULER to it.

Is there a way i can get that kind of control or a MSword control without save button.

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to get a "Word Control" into a webpage (not least since that requires every user of your site to have a copy of Word installed), but you can look into something like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), which is a WYSIWYG editor written in Javascript/HTML. Getting a ruler in there may be difficult though.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  I'm not sure what your question is, but what you are referring to is a WYSIWYG editor.  There are many versions and options for embedding one in your web page.  You mention one already.  Here's some more:

- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
- [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)
- [YUI Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such a MS Office control called aceoffix. It works like calling MS Office from local machine and embeding it in web browser. Users can edit,view and save document online diretly. Developer can also customize these functions, such as disable the "save" button.